# Add a button to an anchor in a wordpress shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress

This site has been a lifesaver of later and I must yet again ask for assistance with something that will seem trivial to most of you.

How do I replace the text anchor with an image in the following shortcode:

[video_lightbox_youtube video_id="" width="640" height="480" anchor="We have arrived!"]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the anchor text with image, just give you image url in anchor attribute of shortcode.

Please refer below:

```
[video_lightbox_youtube video_id="" width="640" height="480" anchor="http://www.example.com/images/vimeo-thumb.jpg"]
```